# Postgresql: Searching within arrays for an arbitrary number of inputs

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a record in my table (table1) whose name is "Jonh Wood Doe Smith" and I want to return it even if the user types any of the possible combinations: "John Doe", "Jonn Wood Smith", etc

I implemented a collumn (fullName) which is an array with all the names and was thinking to search it like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ({"Wood","Doe"}) IN ANY (fullName)
```

Do you know if this is possible and/or what is the best approach to this kind of problem? I will use postgresql so proprietary methods, functions, etc is not a problem. It doesn't need to be a method compatible with other DBs.

Note: fullName is a collumn like this {"John", "Wood", "Doe", "Smith"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use array operator `<@` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE array['Wood','Doe'] <@ fullname;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0030d/2)

But what you really should do is get interested in [full text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/textsearch.html)